# How can i see sessions and session information in IIS without code

Tags: iis

I want to see the sessions active and their information in IIS.
I know i can do this with code.But I don't want to write code.
can any one tell me how it is possible.

Comment: Sessions are strictly controlled by the web apps and their frameworks, so you can only see them via code. Usually session related might be printed out to IIS log files, if you use enhanced logging to write certain headers, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-85/enhanced-logging-for-iis85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, if you want to view active sessions/connections to my web pages on IIS. I suggest you could consider using IIS worker process feature.

You couold open the IIS managment console, at the server level you could click on "Worker Processes".

Then doubleclick the worker process to open the Requests feature page in where you can view the requests currently processing in the selected application pool.

It will contains the client IP address and related information.

If you want to see current Session and Session Variables, there is nothing built into IIS that will show you this. So either way, you need to develop some custom code to log and/or show this.